# Does changing the Resistor from button debouncing reference design require a cap change?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-design, button

I have a board design using the STM32F411 chip. I have setup the wakeup button circuit as per the Reference Design on the Eval Board.

[image: stm32f4 Reference Circuit]

The value of the Capacitor is 0.1uF.

I need to change the 220K Resistor (R194) to a 5.1K Resistor and am wondering if I need to change the Cap (C92) from 0.1 uF to a higher value as well for debouncing to the same degree.

I have tried to do this by changing to a 4.7uF Capacitor, and simulations [before](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+19.867427341514983+74+5+50%0Ar+352+240+352+320+0+220000%0A172+304+176+304+128+0+6+3.3+3.3+0+0+0.5+Voltage%0Ar+480+336+480+400+0+40000%0Ag+352+320+352+384+0%0Aw+304+176+352+176+0%0Ar+368+176+400+176+0+100%0Ac+416+176+432+176+0+1e-7+0%0Aw+352+176+368+176+0%0Aw+400+176+416+176+0%0Ar+464+240+496+240+0+330%0Aw+448+240+448+176+0%0Aw+496+240+528+240+0%0Aw+448+240+352+240+0%0Aw+448+176+432+176+0%0Aw+464+240+448+240+0%0As+304+176+304+240+0+0+false%0Aw+352+240+304+240+0%0Ao+11+64+0+20483+5+0.00009765625+0+2+11+3%0A) and [after](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+19.867427341514983+74+5+50%0Ar+352+240+352+320+0+5000%0A172+304+176+304+128+0+6+3.3+3.3+0+0+0.5+Voltage%0Ar+480+336+480+400+0+40000%0Ag+352+320+352+384+0%0Aw+304+176+352+176+0%0Ar+368+176+400+176+0+100%0Ac+416+176+432+176+0+0.0000047+3.2999999435895586%0Aw+352+176+368+176+0%0Aw+400+176+416+176+0%0Ar+464+240+496+240+0+330%0Aw+448+240+448+176+0%0Aw+496+240+528+240+0%0Aw+448+240+352+240+0%0Aw+448+176+432+176+0%0Aw+464+240+448+240+0%0As+304+176+304+240+0+1+false%0Aw+352+240+304+240+0%0Ao+11+64+0+20483+5+0.00009765625+0+2+11+3%0A) the change.

In practice:
220K + 0.1uF : No debouncing issues
5.1K + 0.1uF : No debouncing issues
220K + 4.7uF : Debouncing insufficient
5.1K + 4.7uf : Debouncing insufficient

If anyone has any clues as to why a Cap change is not needed or why my change is not behaving as expected, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: It's probably more sensitive to the other edge now with the bigger cap.

Comment: That's not a great debouncing scheme if it's going to pin that is finicky about bouncing either. You may want to redesign it with something like a 555 one-shot.

Comment: Thanks, Can't re-design as we are just re-working boards we already have. The issue was the rising edge now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put a scope on the various nodes in the different circuit configurations to see what is really going on, but here is some speculation on my part.

I think you sized the cap suitably for the resistor change in the case where the switch is opening.  That is confirmed by your simulations.  When the switch opens (assuming it starts closed in steady-state), the cap will charge through R194 and you get the typical voltage decay you would expect.  The timing is about the same with 220k + 0.1uF as for 5.1k + 4.7uF.  I don't think the debounce issues are appearing when the switch opens.

When the switch closes however, the larger cap is being shorted by the switch, with only the 100 Ohm resistor, and its own ESR to restrict current flow.  Take a look at the 'current' through cap (the moving dots) when the switch closes in both simulations.  There is no noticeable current in the case of the 0.1uF cap, but there is some with the larger cap.  This additional ~20X energy stored in the cap to discharge through the switch.  I'm not too sure about the mechanism causing bouncing - the voltage and peak current are not higher, just the period of time is extended, but this might be exacerbating the bouncing.

So I think you would want to try changing the 100 Ohm resistor.  To keep the discharge time low, you would want to decrease that resistor to 5 Ohm (or remove it altogether), but that would lead to higher current through the switch, maybe even too much for the switch to handle.  You could try going the other way with a higher value but that would extend the discharge time and decrease the current.  Based on your results I think a lower value resistor would work better, but again may not be suitable for the switch.

Another thought is that the 0.1uF cap is going to have a higher cut-off frequency than the 4.7uF cap.  So the higher value cap will behave more like a short circuit at lower frequencies than the 0.1uF cap.  Each bounce will produce a burst of frequencies, and perhaps the lower value cap is being counterproductive because of its frequency response.

All that being said, give your observations I would probably just leave the 0.1uF cap in with the 5.1k resistor.